# How to total 2 cells = Take the value in Cell A and if Cell A is blank then take the value from Cell B

Tags: checksum

Cell A Row 1 = 100
Cell B row 1= 100000
Cell C Total should be = 100

Cell A Row 2 = 0
Cell B Row 2 = 45000
Cell C Row 2 = 45000

Total of Cell C1 + C2 = 45100

Comment: To me, your Row 1 math does not add up. Total should be 1000100? Is C1 = A1+B1?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but your question is not properly presented. You will get better answers if you put some time to better explain what you want to do. Please consider the following points:

1. This is group for SuperUser questions, however this is probably an Excel question. From your title, it could be a shell script question, or an SQL question or whatever.
2. In your title you mention "blank" cells, but then, your example, is using a cell with a "0" value. These are not the same.

Supposing that you are referring to excel, cell C1 should have a formula of:

=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1),A1<>0),A1,B1)

and then fill cells in the C column accordingly. Then you can just sum the cells in the C column.